# Mail sent successfully but not receive using codeigniter mail smpt

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I am using codeinter email for sending mail. Mail's sent successfully but it is not received.

Here is my code:

```
function send_verify_email($email)
{
    $email_code = md5($email);

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_crypto'=> 'ssl',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'test@gmil.com', // change it to yours
        'smtp_pass' => '***', // change it to yours
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    // $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('test@gmail.com', "TalentRiser Update Password");
    $this->email->to('receiver@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject("Update Password");                  
    $this->email->message('hello for test');
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: no, it is showing success message but i am not receiving the mail, can you please help me to solve this..

Comment: is there anyone who can help me, with given question?

Comment: Did you read the linked question and the answers? Did you check every point? Server logs, mails logs, etc.?

Comment: yes, when i talk with my hosting provider, they found one error, and the error is " We could see that your domain is calling 'Email.php' file since the file does not exist in your document root folder".  Now i am not getting any solution for solve this error.

Comment: who put this question as a duplicate, where he is give me the ans

Comment: So, you have an error message and somehow a misconfiguration in your `php` files. The only thing I can advise you is that you sit down, check each and every line of your files and configuration. You will find the error, but it takes some time. StackOverflow users don't have access to your server, so nobody can guess which files doesn't exist. Besides. this error message doesn't look as if its related to your email sending issue.